# Get and Set the underlying value of an Enum

Tags: c#, enums

So I am trying really hard to change the underlying number value of an `Enum`. Take this example:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Foo
{
   Foo = 1,
   Bar = 2,
   FooBat = 4
}
```

With a simple extension methods for enums. In his method I want to remove all flags from the enum itself:

```cs
public static TEnum GetBaseVersionOfEnum<TEnum>(this TEnum enumVal) where TEnum : Enum
{
   var tempEnum = enumVal & 0 // I would like to do something like that. e.g. setting its underlying value to zero.
   return tempEnum;
}
```

Note that it is possible to set an enum to zero, even if there is no matching enum member.

To clarify what I want to achieve, here a few samples:

- `Foo.Bar.GetBaseVersionOfEnum()` should return `Foo` with the value of `0`.
- `(Foo.Bar | Foo.Foo).GetBaseVersionOfEnum()` should return `Foo` with the value of `0`.

---

I actually achieved that, but it is hella ugly, at least IMO, by using some reflection. I really hope there is a cleaner and **faster** way to do this.

```cs
var dynamicVal = (dynamic)enumVal;

dynamicVal.value__ = 0;

var tempEnum = (Enum)dynamicVal;
```

I actually stumbled over the `value__` field by some testing with reflection, which revealed that there is actually a **public** field which exposes the current value.

[image]

This also makes me wonder why you can't access it by using *the dot* (enumVal.value__)... I guess it is some kind of runtime field.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you asking to get the enum's value from the enum? For example, for FooBat, you want it to return 4?

Comment: @SILENT No I just want `T`, of type Enum, to be `0` 'thats' all.

Comment: You can't access the field directly because the C# compiler prevents it. You *can* access it in PowerShell, for example, `[System.AttributeTargets]::Assembly.value__` .

Comment: why not `(MyEnum)0`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere It is a generic extension in which I don't have the enum which is being used itself.

Comment: you have `T`and thus can use `(T) 0`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well _TIAS_, you can't cast an int to T in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be deeply confused by your question, but to me it seems you're trying to make a convoluted way of saying [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default):

```cs
public static TEnum GetBaseVersionOfEnum<TEnum>(this TEnum enumVal) where TEnum : Enum
{
    return default;
}
```

The default value for an enum is all-zero bits (the default for the underlying value type). But why do you need a helper for that at all? You can literally say

```cs
Foo allzero;
```

And you get an all-zero enum of your type. Or say

```cs
myExistingEnum = default;
```

to zero an existing variable out.

Comment: Thanks I really didn't thought of that! For some reason if I try this with `Foo.Foo` and `Foo.Bar`. The returned types aren't equal, after I cast them both to `Enum`. Btw I store the results of this method in a `Collection<Enum>`.

Comment: Since the input is ignored, there's little value in it being an extension method anymore.

Comment: @madreflection it doesn't really matter, I just over simplified that method and it shows the full solution to it.

Comment: @Twenty: Very well...  On slight tangent, are you actually referring to `Enum` in the `Collection<>`, or a specific enum type? If it's `Enum`, each value is being boxed.

Comment: @madreflection it is actually `Enum`, because the collection needs to store different Enums, if you can follow me?

Comment: I actually found my problem, I did compare by using `==` and not `IsEqual` and didn't try it with the dictionary. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I do follow. Just understand that they're being boxed. Yes, `System.Enum` inherits from `System.ValueType`, but because it's not sealed, it's still a reference type, so enum values are boxed when cast to `Enum` just as they are when cast to `object`. That's why the `==` didn't work: they were different boxed instances.

Comment: Note that there is no easy way of storing arbitrary enums in a collection without boxing, since they all can have different underlying value types, possibly with different sizes. You could of course create a special data structure that stored all their bytes in an array and also keep type metadata and their sizes, and then make a generic `Get<TEnum>` method on that, and that sounds like it could avoid boxing. I hope I don't have to emphasise how ridiculously overcomplicated that would be.

Comment: @V0ldek also I think this all can't be achieved with reflection right, since you are talking about type metadata?

Comment: @Twenty You'd have to get reflection there _somewhere_, since I don't think there's a way of accessing the underlying type of an enum without using its type metadata.